# Get slugs and ids of wordpress category children

Tags: wordpress, categories, children

I m getting the slug and id of one of the my-category children.

Not sure how to grab slugs and ids from all children.

```
$incat = get_category_by_slug("my-category");

    foreach((get_the_category()) as $inchild):

      if (cat_is_ancestor_of($incat, $inchild)):

         $my_category_name = strtolower( str_replace(" ", "-", $inchild->slug) );
         $my_category_id = $inchild->cat_ID;

      endif;

    endforeach;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

`get_categories('child_of=X')`;

where 'X' is your parent category name..

It will return an array that can be manipulated through foreach.

For more info you can checkout -
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories